# Which words or grammar forms are likely to cause a collision between American and British English?

Tags: north-american-english, transatlantic-differences, insular-english

For all the Mickey-taking on both sides of the water I suppose British and American speakers understand one another 99% of the time.

**Can anyone think of any areas of vocabulary or grammar where serious confusion could arise?**

The only word of which I am aware, which in America is the near antonym of its British meaning is *nervy*. To an American, saying someone is *nervy* means they have nerves of steel such as a high-wire performer. In Britain it means they are of a nervous disposition almost to the point of breakdown.

This question has been inspired by a European OP who has queried which form of English it is desirable to learn to *avoid his worlds colliding*.

**Edit**
Clearly one could look up one of the many books on sale that provide translations from American to British and vice-versa. It was not my intention in asking the question, that we should compile yet another of those. What I thought would be interesting would be to hear of some actual instances of where you could get into serious difficulty, perhaps an anecdote or two.

Comment: I suppose it’s only serious to those of us who take *haute cuisine* seriously, but when my American mouth’s hankering for salty chips, savoury fries just don’t cut it!

Comment: I'm sure by now nearly everyone knows the more common US/UK differences (words like ***fag, pissed, pants***) that used to cause so much sniggering in the past. But to be honest, I can't even remember a time when people on either side of the pond didn't actually *know* those words had different connotations on the other side. All that's changed is we've got bored with people making lame jokes about them.

Comment: All seriousness aside re the nouns mentioned above (chips=fries, where that difference is well known and trivial), the [once] different meanings of the adjective “savo[u]ry” did prompt me to ask [this somewhat relevant question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12292/is-the-french-adjective-savoureuxse-ever-used-to-mean-sal%C3%A9e-or-non-sucr) about it on the French StackExchange site.

Comment: Many US speakers would not understand "mickey-taking". We say "Watch your head!" when warning someone not to bump their head.

Comment: Yes. *Watch your head* makes you think doesn't it! But I'm not sure that anyone ever bumped theirs as a result of misunderstanding what it meant.

Comment: I'm in the US and to me, *nervy* means annoying (as in "they have some nerve to do that!")

Comment: Since there's lots of references,as you mention, that cover the vocabulary differences, I think it would be more useful to ask for _grammatical_ differences, e.g. 'at the hospital' vs 'at hospital'.

Comment: @KristinaLopez We talk about *having a nerve*, but I don't think *nervy* has that connotation with us. It means *of a nervous disposition*.

Comment: @Mitch That particular one has been done to death on this site. But good idea. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TimRomano but the mind is in the head, is it not?  Mind your feet...

Comment: @WS2 AmE/BrE syntax differences 'done to death' here? Do you have any links?

Comment: @Mitch *Done to death* is a modern metaphorical idiom (perhaps just UK used - I don't know) meaning that something has been overdone to the point where people are totally fed up with it.

Comment: @WS2 I'm a native speaker so I have a good idea what it means. I question the reality of that. Do you have more than one link that you can convince me of the high frequency of grammar comparisons between AmE and BrE here?

Comment: @Mitch Do you mean as regards the relative frequency of *done to death* on either side of the Atlantic?

Comment: 'Batted around' has caused some red faces when my tennis-playing relatives visited from England.

Answer (score 3):

I remember reading somewhere that the opposing meanings of the term "to table" on either side of the pond caused confusion at meetings between the British and American heads of state during the second world war.

edit: found it, from Winston Churchill's book *The Second World War, Volume III, The Grand Alliance*:

The enjoyment of a common language was of course a supreme advantage in all British and American discussions. The delays and often partial misunderstandings which occur when interpreters are used were avoided. There were however differences of expression, which in the early days led to an amusing incident. The British Staff prepared a paper which they wished to raise as a matter of urgency, and informed their American colleagues that they wished to "table it." To the American Staff "tabling" a paper meant putting it away in a drawer and forgetting it. A long and even acrimonious argument ensued before both parties realized that they were agreed on the merits and wanted the same thing.

Comment: It sounds as if "tabling" something in America would amount to what we would call "shelving it".  If you "shelf" something it amounts to much the same thing as "kicking it into the long grass".

Answer (score 1):

A few examples right off the bat:

- The word *spunk* has a secondary offensive meaning in British English
- *Pants* are undergarments in British English and outer wear in American English
- Floor numbering is different. Brits have a *ground floor*, just like Germans, the Dutch and other European countries. In America, the first floor is on the ground.
- The C-word is a lot less offensive to Brits, although still shouldn't be used lightly
- The word *spaz* is a derogatory name for a person having cerebral palsy, or, as an insult, a stupid person in British English. In American English it means to have a freakout and is more often used as a verb
- (this came from some googling) the word *quite* has some hidden dangers ("quite good" might be understood as worse than just "good")

---

Bottom line: the most differing parts seem to be slang and swearing

Comment: As a Brit who's spent nearly 30 years on both sides of the Atlantic, the differences are far fewer than you'd imagine - grammar issues are limited to "likely" in the middle of a sentence, for example (*it'll likely rain tomorrow*), or "a couple" being used as an ordinal (*a couple minutes*). Most issues come from our old friend the idiom: sports analogies, particular sayings, etc. - so not the underlying formal language itself, as that's 100% intelligible from context if nothing else.

Comment: Oh, and using *spaz* in the UK will get you really hard stares - it's equivalent to a racial epithet in most quarters. As for *spunk*... you mean it has a primary meaning in BrE that isn't vulgar? :)

Comment: Clearly one could look up one of the many books on sale that provide translations from American to British. It was not my intention in asking the question to compile yet another of those. What I thought would be interesting would be to hear of some actual instances of where you could get into serious difficulty, perhaps an anecdote or two.

Comment: Re. your assertion about the C word being less offensive in Britain, I'm not sure my auntie would have agreed with you.

Comment: @ProfYaffle Re *spunk*: The "secondary" meaning you are thinking of, is only sense 5c in the OED. There are many earlier meanings from the 16th century - many to do with *spark*. Sense 5a, which was used by my headmaster in the 1950s (to our sniggering amusement) has to do with *spirit, mettle, courage, pluck*. It is totally out of fashion now. I also think it may have been used by Enid Blyton (though I have no reference) oblivious, it would seem, of the then current sense of the word, which had replaced *mettle* as slang for *sperm*.

Comment: There was also apparently a drink being marketed as "spunk in a bottle" or something like that. Didn't go well.

Comment: @ProfYaffle *a couple minutes* seems to be relatively new.  A couple of decades ago, it was always *a couple of minutes.*  I suspect that the *of* is dropping out because of quick speech, and I am not convinced that it is a purely American phenomenon.  htmlcoderexe: in my youth (1970s), spaz was most definitely used as an insult, and frequently as a noun.  I haven't heard the word used very much one way or the other in the last couple of decades, so I suppose you're right and that usage has changed.

Comment: @WS2 the c-word is *heard* (by me at least) far more out of the mouths of British people.  I have always assumed that this is because the taboo is much stronger for Americans.  Certainly, for Americans the c-word taboo is a few orders of magnitude stronger than the f-word taboo.

Comment: @WS2 Exactly my point - I think the ejaculate definition is the primary meaning nowadays. If you stopped people on the street and asked for a definition, you're unlikely to get lashings of ginger beer... (oh, and https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WoJCBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT15&ots=McAL7lkWWZ&dq=blyton%20spunk&pg=PT14#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @phoog Well you didn't have D.H.Lawrence did you! The real reason may be that it is also a profound insult for a male to be called such a thing. But when the then England football captain, John Terry, was caught on video (sound recognition only having been possible from expert lip-readers) to have called an opponent *a black c---*, it was the use of the word *black* which caused him trouble and ended his international career, not the word which followed.

Comment: @ProfYaffle Ah. well done. So I was right - and I've remembered that *Anne had spunk* from circa sixty years ago. So the old memory cells are not in too bad nick.

Comment: @ProfYaffle Oops no. It wasn't Anne it was the *ragamuffin girl* who had *spunk*. No doubt that old Enid perpetuated the British social-class stereotypes for decades beyond their *use-by date*.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but my impression is that in England, to "knock (someone) up" means to go to their house and knock on the door.  In America, it means to make someone pregnant.

Also "pissed" in England usually means drunk.  In America, it's short for "pissed off", which means "very angry".